# SQL variable returning 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

When I run the following SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio it returns a count of 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Daisy_Copy2 
WHERE ChargeCode = '1';
```

But for some reason when I run the following VB.net code the `result` variable returns a 0 and doesn't identify that duplicate codes exist.

```
Dim result As Integer
Using cmdb = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Daisy_Copy2 WHERE ChargeCode = '1'", conn)

Int(result = cmdb.ExecuteScalar())

If result > 1 Then
   MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Codes Exist!", "Billing", _
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
Else
   MsgBox(result)
End If
End Using
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have changed the code from ExecuteNonQuery to Int(result = cmdb.ExecuteScalar()), but it still returns 0 ? I am new to VB, so I may have the syntax wrong? Thanks

Comment: updated with vb.net syntax - try my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Morten, it works with the updated Syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you should use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim result As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Answer (score 2):

[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is normally used for updates or inserts that don't leave a result, so it returns an integer telling you how many rows were affected, not the result itself.

What you most likely are meaning to use is [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query, in this case the integer containing your count.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a way you can use:

```
Dim Sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) AS tCount FROM Daisy_Copy2 WHERE ChargeCode=1", conn)
Dim sqlds = New DataSet



Sqlda.Fill(sqlds, "Daisy_Copy2")

Dim tblRow As DataRow
For Each tblRow In sqlds.Tables("Daisy_Copy2").Rows
    MsgBox(tblRow("tCount").ToString())
Next
```

use below link to read more about it

[System.Data.SqlClient Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Good luck